# Specifying a forward lookup jar in ant file

Tags: java, ant

I need some help in compiling my java project through an ANT file.
Lets there are five subproject in my complete project.
Each subproject has its own ant file to compile it.
for example:

1. subprojectA
2. subprojectB
3. subprojectC
4. subprojectD
5. subprojectE

Now the situation is :
I am using some classes of "subprojectC" in "subprojectA" but as my compilation sequence is 1,2 3,4,5, I am getting error as class can not be resolved while compiling subprojectA.

So, the question is, is it possible to somehoe specify or tell ANT file of "subprojectA" that these classes will be present in future in suppose jarx.

I am looking some kind of forward lookup in ant file.

Thank You

Comment: you need to change compilation sequence. or do you look for a way to tell ant that it needs to find the sequence itself?

Comment: If subprojectA depends on subprojectC, subprojectC needs to be built first.  In fact, this is pretty much what the `depends` attribute of Ant's target element is for.

Comment: @thst: I can't change the compilation sequence. I looking a way to tell ant file that theses classes will be present in future. Actually when I am making the war file, all the subproject will be inside the same war file. So while runtime I don't see any issue, only at the compile time i am facing it. or to oversome I have to copy the full class files in the subproject which I want to compile first. I will work but this is some kind of duplicate code in the same project.

Comment: you have a circular dependency then? Split the project, move the problematic classes from B to new project 0, A deps 0 and B deps 0. Your project structure is broken not ant or java. There is no forward declaration. You can also refactor interfaces out from your classes and put them in your own project.